# Is the code "mutex.unlock if mutex.owned?" safe in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex

The following simplified code (extracted from a rather big multi-threaded piece of software) very rarely results in a `ThreadError: Attempt to unlock a mutex which is not locked`:

```
begin
  yield(mutex) if mutex.try_lock
ensure
  mutex.unlock if mutex.owned?
end
```

on line 4.

That's in Ruby 2.1.5, which is EOF right now, but my understanding was that calling `mutex.unlock` is safe if current thread owns the mutex, which is being checked with `mutex.owned?`. Would I be wrong in this assumption?

I believe that `yield(mutex)` in line 2 does never attempt to unlock the yielded mutex.

I understand that using something like `mutex.synchronize(&block)` may be preferable instead - but I'm just wondering how the above snippet should behave. And if I'm missing something in my understanding.